# Can someone explain this line of zsh shell code for me please?

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt

I am creating a custom zsh prompt based on this zsh theme https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/jonathan.zsh-theme but I'm having difficulty deciphering this line of code...

```
local promptsize=${#${(%):---(%n@%m:%l)---()--}}
```

Could someone please explain it?

Comment: [zsh Manual - 13 Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) (hint: `promptsize` is simply a variable holding the prompt size, e.g. `${#.....}`, the `${(%....}` is the prompt from which the length is taken) Personally, I like single-line prompts, try `PS1="%F{243}%T %F{27}%m:%~>%f "` for user and `PS1="%F{243}%T %F{27}%m:%F{1}%~ %F{27}#%f "` for root.

Comment: Wouldn't be `${#${(%)PS1}}` be an easier way to get the length of the (expanded) prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The outer `${# ... }` returns the length of its (inner) argument,  `${(%)....}`. The `%` modifier causes prompt expansion of what follows. Hence, `:---(%n@%m:%l)---()--` is interpreted as prompt string, and `promptsize` is set to the size of this prompt in **expanded** form.